# Get permanent direct link to embed in <img> (Like Share Link)

Tags: onedrive

I am uploading images to users OneDrive like this:

```
POST /drive/items/{folder-id}/children
```

So now I need to give the user a direct link to the PNG. I'm trying to get a shared link that is direct, so I can place it in `<img src="HERE">` but I am having no luck. Dropbox and Google Drive offered these direct links. Does OneDrive as well?

The `createLink` endpoint gives a link that takes user to a page, it cannot be placed in `img` tag.

Comment: Is this not possible? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to generate a link according to OneDrive File Picker SDK for JavaScript, demo at 
https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v6/js-picker-open.htm

Choose Download link

File #1
Filename: ASCIIfy-StarFunv2.gif
File Link: h t t p : / / public.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y3mYIAJ94eR729crwJ_B9nUg0m0tNn3BS5hhonaEz63xSmsEC-kF5Y-iN9poeWIj6QTiXLU3bI0xk8VKcTP5mTYras8b9F5hZ1eUH-wUcAqpA_4oWHbIkldd6KcXviMEb2wIPZV-HWcnpZryo0JES3mSkj6dZxtifzf0WqseXHDKdeV1t7g4SVWs1IluFazqTRq
Size: 2108 bytes
Link Type: downloadLink
Thumbnail Count: 3

"y3mYIAJ94eR729crwJ_B9nUg0m0tNn3BS5hhonaEz63xSmsEC-kF5Y-iN9poeWIj6QTiXLU3bI0xk8VKcTP5mTYras8b9F5hZ1eUH-wUcAqpA_4oWHbIkldd6KcXviMEb2wIPZV-HWcnpZryo0JES3mSkj6dZxtifzf0WqseXHDKdeV1t7g4SVWs1IluFazqTRq" 
is the file name

Choose Web link

Result 
File #1
Filename: ASCIIfy-Bear.gif
File Link: h t t p s : / / onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8F99649728BEB2F3!2737&authkey=!ANtMXD2ftQHfxCs
Size: 5234 bytes
Link Type: webLink
Thumbnail Count: 3

Comment: Thanks very much Markus, I'll try it out!

Comment: Ah nice it gives me this link `https://public-sn3301.files.1drv.com/y3mhay4_vygbACBJ9-gF7pQa-MTqZ-rqt4vBW-beYjO5POMUoLxyCVMwHAreyYU4GjaB2l0AA7wF9zVUMN5kfSpGbV1-reD7v2_O7p0Y4YN3mml8GmluQ4AfSQjJiH-vGYnLO6VUIi15bnfD7qoe_9VT1Q5DNAhyXJC26NdTmakk4ehM87YGlV9dm838NG06oj2HVWcaC_66O6Zt5O_YB_LIw` however when I navigate to it, its forcing the download to happen, instead of displaying it. Do you know how to make it display rather then download? If I request `webLink` it opens in the viewer - `https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=c2c2e10fef4f47f9&id=C2C2E10FEF4F47F9!403&sff=1&authkey=!AGUtNY8y50bqS4s ` :(

Comment: @Noitidart have exactly that problem as can't get an indirect link from OneDrive. Did you find a solution, by any chance?

Comment: @giosans - back then I never found a solution. I'm surprised they still haven't resolved this almost 3 years later.